# Incompatible types when creating new string array and cannot find symbol when accessing another class variable

Tags: java

Incompatible types when creating new string array and cannot find symbol when accessing another class variable.

I have two classes:

- Sistem
- MataKuliah

`Sistem` class:

```
/*
    Test array

*/
import java.util.Scanner;

class Sistem
{
        public static void main (String args[]){
            int counter = 0, jumlahMk;
            String[] namaMk = new String[jumlahMk];


            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            MataKuliah mk = new MataKuliah();

            jumlahMk = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            while(counter<jumlahMk){
                namaMk[counter] = (new String[jumlahMk]);
                namaMk[counter] = in.nextLine();
                counter++;
            }

            mk.printNamaMatkul(namaMK);


        }//end main
}//end class
```

`MataKuliah` class:

```
/*
    MataKuliah class
*/

class MataKuliah{
    void printNamaMatkul(String[] namaMk){
        System.out.println(Sistem.namaMk);

    }
}
```

I know it's basic, please help me! :)

Comment: Change `System.out.println(Sistem.namaMk);` to `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namaMk));`

Answer (score 0):

You can only access fields in another class. A better approach is to pass the data you want to use, which is what you actually did.

```
void printNamaMatkul(String[] words){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
}
```

The name of the parameter doesn't have to match the argument you passed to it. i.e. you can write

```
printNamaMatkul(namaMk);
```

but it would make more sense to make the name of the method generic

```
void printArray(String[] words){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
}

printArray(namaMk);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your program.

1. `namaMk[counter] = (new String[jumlahMk]);` This statement is incorrect as you are trying to convert `String` to `String[]` here.
2. You have not given the size of `namaMk` Array.
3. You are trying to refer the private member of another class by doing `System.out.println(Sistem.namaMk);`
4. You are creating the object of class `MataKuliah` directly in `static main` block.

You need to correct all the above problem to get your code running.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public class MataKuliah {
    public void printNamaMatkul(String[] namaMK) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namaMK));
    }
}

class Sistem
{
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        /* Create a new instance of Sistem */
        Sistem sistem = new Sistem();
        sistem.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        int counter = 0, jumlahMk;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        /* This will be valid now */
        MataKuliah mk = new MataKuliah();

        jumlahMk = in.nextInt();
        /* Create the String[] Array */
        String[] namaMk = new String[jumlahMk];
        in.nextLine();
        while(counter < jumlahMk){
            namaMk[counter] = in.nextLine();
            counter++;
        }
        mk.printNamaMatkul(namaMk);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
3
foo
bar
foobar
```

Output:

```
[foo, bar, foobar]
```